# POST variables disappearing when a link is clicked

Tags: php, variables, post, state

I just setup some pagination for a search, and the search uses POST variables to define what to search for etc. In my URL I can set the pagination offset like this search/OFFSET, and my links in the pagination link there correctly. However, when I click a link all POST variables vanish even if I explicitly set them so I can use them in the next script. I'm using codeigniter and I have GET turned off and really don't want to store these 5-6 values in a session since then it will get all clumsy.

Does clicking a link fully reload the page and delete POST variables?

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone know how to enable query strings manually with codeigniter? Not globally in settings, but only to use within the search controller?

Comment: You can [add your own routing rules](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) to receive these variables as URL segments, so there's no need to use the query string or to resort to POST.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, clicking a link creates a GET request so wouldn't keep any of the POST data. Although it's technically possible to do so with javascript, that's a bad idea.

This is an entirely appropriate use of GET, please read [this fuller explanation](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, clicking a link removes all the POST variables.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to change your php page that receives the request?  You might want to adjust your variables there to accept either GET or POST:

```
$defaultvalue='';//change this to '' or NULL or whatever you want
$searchQuery = (isset($_POST['s']) ? $_POST['s'] : (isset($_GET['s'])?$_GET['s']: $defaultvalue));
```

Then your php page will be better equipped to handle either GET or POST

Comment: Yes, I have full access to everything. The trick is that GET variables are removed by the framework by default as GET variables are disabled in the config (and will stay so). That's why I use POST to work around it.

Comment: Hmmm, that seems odd to me.  So if you have something like domain.com/search.php?q=elephants&page=3, you have no ability to access that page param? That seems VERY limiting to me

Comment: If you *really* want to, you can set session or cookie values to the search queries that were initially provided in the POST, but that's just as bad as the javascript faking a POST solution Long Ears said

Answer (score 0):

POST data will only be present during the original request (i.e. it does not persist between requests). If you want data to persist, use sessions. However, it is common practice to use GET for search queries and pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an incredibly ugly workaround and set a form full of hidden fields to submit when you click a link. I really wouldn't recommended it though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a form that submits some set of post variables to the action parameter with the get variables. So the form should submit a post request to http://www.somedomain.com/FormSubmit.php?pag=1&sort=asc  This would submit the post values of that form along with the get values of the string. If you can change your link to a form button, you should be good to go.